# powershell Command working from console but not from script

Tags: powershell

ve got the following script that I'm trying to use to remotely install our build (an msi), see below.

The thing is that it's not working, but the curious thing is that if I run the commands from a PowerShell console then it works.

I've just tested running the install on one remote server and it worked fine (I got a return code of 0 and I also checked in the remote server and it had installed fine)

So my question is what Am I missing here?

Why do the commands work fine when running them from a PS console but not when using a script?

TIA

```
   param ($serverfile, $targetdir, $domainname, $username, $password,)

   if (-not($serverfile) -or -not($targetdir) -or -not($domainname) -or -not($username))
   {
   echo "error"
   exit
   }

     #default to c:\temp, this needs to be in the server
    $dest = "c$\temp\"

    #This is really good as it allows us to have some sort of type safety
    $srvs = Import-Csv $serverfile

    foreach ($item in $srvs) 
    { 
     if ($item.Type -eq "App" )
     {
        $name = $item.Hostname
        $path = "\\$name\" + $dest

        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path -Force

        Copy-Item -Path '.\Deployment.msi' -Destination $path -Force

        $wmi = "\\" +$name + "\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product" 

        echo "Start Install Product"

        $product = ([WMIClass]$wmi)
        $var = $product.Install("c:\temp\Deployment.msi", "TARGETDIR=$targetdir DOMAINNAME=$domainname EMANRESU=$username PASSWORD=$password", $true)

        if ($var.ReturnValue -ne 0)
        { 
          echo "Error installing Deployment.msi on $name"
          echo "exit code: $var.ReturnValue"
        }   

        echo "Installed Product on $name"
     }
```

Edit:

If I hard code the names of the servers, eg:

```
$path = '\\uk703\c$\temp\'
$wmi = '\\uk703\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product'
```

then everything works fine

So clearly the issue is down to my lack of understanding on how variables are expanded, etc...

Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: i've edited the post to include parameters

Comment: Can you post the command you are trying to run in console as well as the other method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working full details in my blog [here](http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/install-and-uninstall-msi-remotely.html)

In essence I've used [string]::Format() and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your script is not signed in an environment that requires it (i.e. the PS mode is has a "Restricted" execution policy). Here is a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) to help you.

Comment: policy is set to unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

One minor miscode (not the reason of the script failure obviously), you are expanding a variable property in a string in the wrong way:

```
"exit code: $var.ReturnValue"
```

the proper way is:

```
"exit code: $($var.ReturnValue)"
```